# Angular JS Factory Variables is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been attempting to create a script that grabs session data from a PHP API using Angular JS to create authentication.

I have created a factory called `User` and in my `loginController` I use `User.Initialise()` to check whether the session in PHP has a `user_id` attached to it.

When using `User.Initialise()` in my `loginController` (bare in mine my session has a user attached to it) it will use `$location.path("/dashboard")` to change the route to the dashboard. The dashboard route has a controller that has the variable `$scope.UserID` which is assigned using `User.Session.user_id`, however, when I attempt to call `User.Session` it returns undefined, even though `User.Initialise();` assigns it in the `loginController`.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

```
var $Gladium = angular.module("Gladium", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "ngSanitize"]);

$Gladium.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider.when("/",{
        templateUrl: "pages/login.html",
        controller: "loginController"
    }).when("/dashboard",{
        templateUrl: "pages/dashboard.html",
        controller: "dashboardController"
    }).when("/error/:error_code", {
        templateUrl: "pages/system_error.html",
        controller: "errorController"
    });

});

/* Controllers */
$Gladium.controller("dashboardController", function($scope, User){
    console.log("Services:");
    console.log(User.Session);

});
$Gladium.controller("loginController", function($scope, $location, User){

    User.Initialise().then(function(){
        $scope.Authenticate = true;
        if(User.loggedIn()){
            $location.path("/dashboard");
        }
    });

    /* Variables */
    $scope.Email;
    $scope.Password;

    $scope.Login = function(){
        if(User.logIn($scope.Email, $scope.Password)){
            $location.path("/dashboard");
            return true;
        }
    }



});
$Gladium.controller("errorController", function($scope, $routeParams){

    $scope.Errors = {
        "request": "We couldn't process that request at this time. Please try again later.",
        "unknown": "An unknown error occurred if this is persistant please contact technical support."
    };

    $scope.currentError =  $scope.Errors[$routeParams["error_code"]];

});

/* Factories */
$Gladium.factory("User", function($http, $location){

    var Session;
    var Error;

    return {

        Initialise: function(){
            return $http.get("core.php?do=getSession").then(function(requestData){

                if(requestData.data["requestStatus"] == 1){
                    Session = requestData.data.data;
                }else{
                    $location.path("/error/request");
                    return false;
                }

            });
        },


        loggedIn: function(){
            if(Session["user_id"] != 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        },

        logOut: function(){
            if(Session["user_id"] != 0 ){
                $http.post("core.php",{
                    do: "logout"
                }).then(function(requestData){
                    if(requestData.data["requestStatus"] == 1){

                    }else{

                    }
                });
            }else{
                console.warn("There is no user session to logout.");
            }
        },

        logIn: function(Email, Password){
            $http.post("core.php",{
                do: "login",
                email: Email,
                password: Password
            }).then(function(requestData){
                if(requestData.data["requestStatus"] == 1){

                    Data = requestData.data;

                    if(Data["actionStatus"] == 1){
                        Initialise();
                    }else{
                        Error = Data["Error"];
                        return false;
                    }

                }else{
                    $location.path("/error/request");
                    return false;
                }

                $location.path("/error/unknown");
                return false;
            });
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Add 'User' refernce in controller $Gladium.controller("loginController", ['$scope', '$location', 'User',function($scope, $location, User){

Comment: Whats the difference between that and injecting it? Could you elaborate?

Comment: changing to the syntax that @NagaveerGowda suggested would only be to make the app minification safe.  If you aren't minifying the scripts, the syntax you are using here is fine, though somewhat substandard.  it definitely wouldn't affect your error, but it could create a different kind of error, if the app is minified....

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question. I'm not minifying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that u just forget to return the `Session` variable which should be a property of `User` Service

```
....
$Gladium.factory("User", function($http, $location){

var Session;
var Error;

return {
    // return the Session so it can be accessed via User.Session, or it is a variable in private closure
    Session:Session
    Initialise: function(){
        return $http.get("core.php?do=getSession").then(function(requestData){

            if(requestData.data["requestStatus"] == 1){
                Session = requestData.data.data;
            }else{
                $location.path("/error/request");
                return false;
            }

        });
    },
....
```

### UPDATE

Sorry the change above won't solve your problem since you are assigning the `Session` closure variable, which will not change `User.Session`.In this way it still remains undefined.

There are several ways for you to solve this problem.

One i think that is the most simple is to keep the `Session` private and access it via a get function `User.getSession()`.

```
$Gladium.factory("User", function($http, $location){

var Session;
var Error;

return {
// use get function to get Session
getSession:function(){
  return Session;
},
Initialise: function(){
    return $http.get("core.php?do=getSession").then(function(requestData){

        if(requestData.data["requestStatus"] == 1){
            Session = requestData.data.data;
        }else{
            $location.path("/error/request");
            return false;
        }

    });
},
....
```

In this way u can access your `Session` by `User.getSession()`.

Comment: Still undefined, sorry.